# HTML DOM appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Basically I wanted to present dynamic data on HTML components. Here is my html:

```
<div id="colorGradiant"></div>
```

And the script to get data and append the content to the html component:

```
 function showColorLegendBox(max)
    {
        var content = "<div id='colorGradiant' style='border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; left:0px; top: 10px; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; font-family: Helvetica; width: 256px; z-index: 10000000000; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 0px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;'><h3 style='padding:0;margin:0;text-align:center;font-size:16px;'>Cases Severity</h3><ul style='position: relative; font-size: 12px; display: block; list-style: none; margin: 0px; height: 15px;'><li style='position:absolute;left:0.5px'>0</li><li style='position:absolute;left:42.5px'>" + Math.round(max/5*1) +"</li><li style='position:absolute;left:93.5px'>" + Math.round(max/5*2) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:144.5px'>" + Math.round(max/5*3) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:195.5px'>" + Math.round(max/5*4) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:238.5px'>" + max + "</li></ul><div style='position: relative; display: block; width: 256px; height: 15px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: black; background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);'></div></div>";
        var html = document.getElementById("colorGradiant");
        html.appendChild(content);
}
```

However, by using these codes, it throw me an error message which is Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null. I wonder is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
function showColorLegendBox(max)
{
    $('opacitydiv').empty();
    var content = "<h3 style='padding:0;margin:0;text-align:center;font-size:16px;'>Cases Severity</h3><ul style='position: relative; font-size: 12px; display: block; list-style: none; margin: 0px; height: 15px;'><li style='position:absolute;left:0.5px'>0</li><li style='position:absolute;left:42.5px'>" + Math.round(max/5*1) +"</li><li style='position:absolute;left:93.5px'>" + Math.round(max/5*2) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:144.5px'>" + Math.round(max/5*3) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:195.5px'>" + Math.round(max/5*4) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:238.5px'>" + max + "</li></ul><div style='position: relative; display: block; width: 256px; height: 15px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: black; background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);'></div>";
    $("#opacitydiv").append(content);

    //Hide the other elements of opacitydiv
    document.getElementById('opacitytext').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('opacityselect').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('opacityslider').style.display = "none";

    //Adjust the css for opacitydiv
    document.getElementById('opacitydiv').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("opacitydiv").style.width="25%";
}

function queryMHC()
{           
        if (heatmap_MHC) {
            heatmap_MHC.setMap(null);
        }   
        var visitAPI = "http://mhclivemap.appsolutrends.net/api/visits?" +
                "start=" + $('#startDate').val() + "&end=" + $('#endDate').val() + 
                "&diagnosis=" + $('#mhc_type_select').val();

           $.ajax({      
                url: "/main/Redirect.aspx?url=" + encodeURIComponent(visitAPI),
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain:true,
                success: function (res) {                   
                   var gradient = [
                                    'rgba(185, 185, 203, 0)',
                                    'rgba(145, 145, 192, 0)',
                                    'rgba(65, 65, 207, 0)',
                                    //dark blue
                                    'rgba(30, 30, 229, 1)',
                                    //light blue
                                    'rgba(0, 185, 255, 1)',
                                    'rgba(0, 255, 215, 1)',                                     
                                    //green
                                    'rgba(0, 255, 15, 1)',
                                    'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
                                    //yellow
                                    'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 235, 0, 1)',
                                    //red
                                    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
                                  ]

                    var result = res.visits;
                    var data = [];
                    var max = 0;

                    for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++) { // iterate thru each element in array
                        var count = result[i].count;
                        data.push({
                            location: new google.maps.LatLng(result[i].lat, result[i].lon),
                            weight: count
                        });

                        if (count > max) {
                            max = count;
                        }
                    }

                    heatmap_MHC = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                      data: data,
                      radius: 30,
                      opacity: 0.8,
                      maxIntensity: max
                    });
                    heatmap_MHC.set('gradient', gradient);
                    heatmap_MHC.setMap(map);

                    showColorLegendBox(max);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('unable to load this layer, please try again later');
                }
            });
```

}

Comment: where's max parameter in your function returnig?

Comment: `.appendChild` is a DOM method which takes a DOM element, NOT an HTML string.  jQuery `.append()` will take either if you call it on a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)**

```
 var content = "<div id='colorGradiant' style='border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; left:0px; top: 10px; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; font-family: Helvetica; width: 256px; z-index: 10000000000; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 0px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;'><h3 style='padding:0;margin:0;text-align:center;font-size:16px;'>Cases Severity</h3><ul style='position: relative; font-size: 12px; display: block; list-style: none; margin: 0px; height: 15px;'><li style='position:absolute;left:0.5px'>0</li><li style='position:absolute;left:42.5px'>" + Math.round(max/5*1) +"</li><li style='position:absolute;left:93.5px'>" + Math.round(max/5*2) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:144.5px'>" + Math.round(max/5*3) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:195.5px'>" + Math.round(max/5*4) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:238.5px'>" + max + "</li></ul><div style='position: relative; display: block; width: 256px; height: 15px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: black; background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);'></div></div>";
    $("#colorGradiant").append(content);
```

update if you want with javaScript
then use `innerHTML`  thanks @NoGray for suggestion :)

```
html.innerHTML = content;
```

Comment: If @Carol is not using jquery, set the innerHTML `html.innerHTML = content;`

Comment: It solved the error but the component is not showing up

Comment: inspect element and check the element is added or not

Comment: @Riturajratan Can you help me check the edited portion? What I a trying to is when the dropdownlist is selected, it will execute the queryMHC(). From there, it will call the showColorLegendBox(). And each time you select, the DOM should be cleared. but for now, the .append(content) just keep appending the content but not removing previous one.

Comment: then use $("#colorGradiant").html(content);

Answer (score 0):

use little bit jquery and do it as following

```
function showColorLegendBox(max)
{
    var content = "<div>div content....</div>";
    var html = $("#colorGradiant").html(content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function showColorLegendBox(max) {
        var content = "<div id='colorGradiant' style='border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; left:0px; top: 10px; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; font-family: Helvetica; width: 256px; z-index: 10000000000; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 0px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;'><h3 style='padding:0;margin:0;text-align:center;font-size:16px;'>Cases Severity</h3><ul style='position: relative; font-size: 12px; display: block; list-style: none; margin: 0px; height: 15px;'><li style='position:absolute;left:0.5px'>0</li><li style='position:absolute;left:42.5px'>" + Math.round(max / 5 * 1) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:93.5px'>" + Math.round(max / 5 * 2) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:144.5px'>" + Math.round(max / 5 * 3) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:195.5px'>" + Math.round(max / 5 * 4) + "</li><li style='position:absolute;left:238.5px'>" + max + "</li></ul><div style='position: relative; display: block; width: 256px; height: 15px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: black; background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);'></div></div>";
        $('#colorGradiant').append(content);        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try, if you wanted to continue using the DOM:

```
html.lastChild.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', content);
```

This will preserve existing content within the `html` node, rather than overwriting it (as would happen with `html.innerHTML = content;`).